# Await a value change in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, serial-communication

I'm currently working on a project that involve a stepper motor using c# forms and arduino.
I need to know in c# when the motor stops his movement. To do that, I programmed arduino to send a string trough Serial when the movement is finished. Then the string is interpreted by c# so that the app can do other things after that.
I now want to have the same result as the example below, but using **async await**.

I stored the information that the motor stopped in:

movimentFinished = true;

I solved the problem in a terrible way using: while(movimentFinished = false){await Task.Delay(1)}
The difference between a while loop and an await is going to effect other stuff on my WinApp. The while blocks all the application until    movimentFinished == true;

The logic that I want is simple:

MoveMotor();

await "value change"

//do stuff after it finishes

Any help/tip to do that?
Thank you for reading

```
//this funcion will receive an array from arduino as a reply
private void risposta(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            riceved = port.ReadLine();
            rispos = riceved;
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Reply));
        }

//this function will run every time a reply is sent from arduino through serial
private void Reply(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string risposValore = rispos.Substring(2, rispos.Length - 2);
            char[] pcr = rispos.ToCharArray();
            rispos = rispos.Trim();
 
            if (pcr[0] == 'M' && pcr[1] == 'F' && pcr[2] == '1')
            {
                movementFinished = true;
            }
         }


//this funcion will send a serial command to arduino to run the motor
public void MoveTheMotor(int position)
        {
            int command = 1000;
            int movement = command + (position)
            string com1 = movement.ToString();
            port.Write(com1 + "\n");
            movementFinished = false;
        }


private async void Demo()
        {
            MoveTheMotor(800);

            //this while blocks everything until the value is true

            while (movementFinished == false) { await Task.Delay(1); }

            //do something after the motor finished
        }
```

Comment: It's terrible indeed and doesn't even work. `async void` methods can't be awaited. They're only meant for asynchronous event handlers. The OS's timer resolution is 16ms so trying to wait for 1ms won't work either.

Comment: refactor your method to do not return `void` return `Task` instead,

Comment: i think you can achieve what you want removing : ` while (movementFinished == false) { await Task.Delay(1); }` instead add another event after `movementFinished = true;`

Comment: Regarding `async void` methods, you can learn a lot by [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) interesting article.

Comment: Instead of running in this tight loop, try to think differently. It's much more efficient to use event-driven programming. So do something in the `Reply` method when the value is set to true. That way you don't need to wait at all.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a boolean, you need a signal. In the blocking world, this would be a `ManualResetEventSlim` or similar. In the asynchronous world, this would be some form of `TaskCompletionSource`. As such:

```
private TaskCompletionSource movementFinished;

private void Reply(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  if (pcr[0] == 'M' && pcr[1] == 'F' && pcr[2] == '1')
  {
    movementFinished.TrySetResult();
  }
}

public void MoveTheMotor(int position)
{
  ...
  movementFinished = new TaskCompletionSource();
}

private async void Demo()
{
  MoveTheMotor(800);

  await movementFinished.Task;

  //do something after the motor finished
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain why you chose to keep method `Demo()` an async void?

Comment: It's a copy/paste from the question. I do not encourage `async void`.

Comment: I see, thanks for elaborating. So in my understanding `MoveTheMotor()` creates a new instance of `TaskCompletion`. Which will be completed when `movementFinished.TrySetResult()` in `Reply()`  is reached. Only then will `Demo()` continue on that thread. Is this correct?

Comment: Mostly. When the TCS completes, then `Demo` continues executing. The *thread* part follows the async behavior [described on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Thanks Stephen that was a great article, I didn't know this: *it is the type that is awaitable, not the method returning the type. In other words, you can await the result of an async method that returns Task … because the method returns Task, not because it’s async.*